# How to use 'EXIST' in a simple oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have a table called ‘MainTable’ with following data
[image]

Another table called ‘ChildTable’ with following data (foreighn key Number)
[image]

Now I want to fetch those records from ‘ChildTable’ if there exists at least one ‘S’ status.
But if any other record for this number id ‘R’ then I don’t want to fetch it
Something like this-
[image]

I tried following

```
Select m.Number, c.Status from MainTable m, ChildTable c
where EXISTS (SELECT NULL                                 
              FROM ChildTable c2                      
              WHERE  c2.status =’S’ and c2.status <> ‘R’                           
              AND  c2.number = m.number)
```

But here I am getting record having ‘R’ status also, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child records with 'R' might be associated with a maintable record that also has another child record with status 'S' -- that is what your query is asking for.

```
Select
  m.Number,
  c.Status
from MainTable m
join ChildTable c on c.number = m.number
where EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL                                 
        FROM   ChildTable c2                      
        WHERE  c2.status =’S’                         
          AND  c2.number = m.number) and
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL                                 
        FROM   ChildTable c2                      
        WHERE  c2.status =’R’                         
          AND  c2.number = m.number)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
select num, status
from
(select id,  num, status,
sum(decode(status, 'R', 1, 0)) over (partition by num) Rs,
sum(decode(status, 'S', 1, 0)) over (partition by num) Ss
from child_table) t
where t.Rs = 0 and t.Ss >= 1
-- and status = 'S'
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22d01)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ChildrenWithS AS (
    SELECT Number
    FROM ChildTable
    WHERE Status = 'S'
)
,ChildrenWithR AS (
    SELECT Number
    FROM ChildTable
    WHERE Status = 'R'
)
SELECT MaintTable.Number
      ,ChildTable.Status
FROM MainTable
     INNER JOIN ChildTable
         ON MainTable.Number = ChildTable.Number
WHERE MainTable.Number IN (SELECT Number FROM ChildrenWithS)
      AND MainTable.Number NOT IN (SELECT Number FROM ChildrenWithR)
```